# Python program files interfering with other installation

Tags: package-management, python, dpkg

I am trying to install a JDK (Java development Kit) for the purpose of programming in Scala and I keep getting this error:

```
 dpkg: too many errors, stopping
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu5) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-six
 python-wrapt
 python-decorator
 python-ptyprocess
 python-pexpect
 python-simplegeneric
 ipython
 python-pygments
 python-zmq
 ipython-qtconsole
 mercurial-common
 mercurial
 python-pkg-resources
 python-pyflakes
 pyflakes
 python-lazy-object-proxy
 python-logilab-common
 python-astroid
 pylint
 python-antlr
 python-apt
 python-tz
 python-babel
 python-bs4
 python-cairo
 python-chardet
 python-cvxopt
 python-cycler
 python-dateutil
 python-roman
 python-docutils
 python-egenix-mxtools
 python-egenix-mxdatetime
 python-gobject-2
 python-gtk2
 python-glade2
 python-html5lib
 python-pil:amd64
 python-imaging
 python-jdcal
 python-jedi
 python-markupsafe
 python-jinja2
 python-joblib
 python-lxml
 python-pyparsing
 python-numpy
 python-matplotlib
 python-nose
 python-numexpr
 python-openpyxl
Processing was halted because there were too many errors.
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

This has popped up in the past when installing other packages but it usually doesn't halt it. I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: What JDK are you trying to install, and how exactly?

Comment: Looks like you tried to change the system version of Python. Never do that - it will break your system horribly. Restore the original version of Python from the Ubuntu repositories.